# Unpivot pandas DataFrame partly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following table DataFrame

| Items | Description | Store 1 Qty | Store 1 Value | Store 2 Qty | Store 2 Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | Some item name | 5 | 120 | 7 | 240 |
| item 2 | Some other item | 9 | 1234 | 12 | 98 |

is there any easy way on Python to unpivot stores only?
To make it this way:

| Items | Description | Store number | Value | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Some item name | Store 1 | 5 | 120 |

I was thinking about unpivoting it completely and then pivoting it back keeping value and qty as values. But I assume, that some more efficient solution should be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need `Qty, Value` to separate columns convert first columns to `MultiIndex`, so possible use [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by last space to `MultiIndex in columns`, so last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Items','Description'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
df = df.rename_axis(('Store number',None), axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()
print (df)
    Items      Description Store number  Qty  Value
0  item 1   Some item name      Store 1    5    120
1  item 1   Some item name      Store 2    7    240
2  item 2  Some other item      Store 1    9   1234
3  item 2  Some other item      Store 2   12     98
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.melt()` along with `pd.pivot` as below:

```
df_ = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Items', 'Description'])
df_[['Store number', 'Type']] = df_['variable'].str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
df_ = df_.pivot(index=['Items', 'Description', 'Store number'], columns='Type', values='value').reset_index()
print(df_)
Type   Items      Description Store number  Qty  Value
0     item 1   Some item name      Store 1    5    120
1     item 1   Some item name      Store 2    7    240
2     item 2  Some other item      Store 1    9   1234
3     item 2  Some other item      Store 2   12     98
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with `pd.wide_to_long`; first the columns have to be reordered, such that `Qty` and `Value` appear at the front:

```py
columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(n=1).str[::-1].str.join(' ')
temp = df.set_axis(columns, axis = 'columns')
(pd.wide_to_long(temp, 
                 stubnames = ['Qty', 'Value'], 
                 i = ['Items', 'Description'], 
                 j = 'Store Number', 
                 sep = ' ', 
                 suffix='.+')
   .reset_index()
)
    Items      Description Store Number  Qty  Value
0  item 1   Some item name      Store 1    5    120
1  item 1   Some item name      Store 2    7    240
2  item 2  Some other item      Store 1    9   1234
3  item 2  Some other item      Store 2   12     98
```

Below is another possible option:

```py
#pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(index = ['Items', 'Description'], 
                names_to = ('Store Number', '.value'), 
                names_pattern = r"(.+\s\d)\s(.+)")

    Items      Description Store Number  Qty  Value
0  item 1   Some item name      Store 1    5    120
1  item 2  Some other item      Store 1    9   1234
2  item 1   Some item name      Store 2    7    240
3  item 2  Some other item      Store 2   12     98
```

This uses the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/).

Explanation: The columns you wish to reshape has a pattern (the store number is followed by either Qty or Value); we take advantage of this in the `names_pattern` with a regular expression of groups (`r"(.+\s\d)\s(.+)"`) - the first group points to `Store 1/Store2`, while the other group points to `Qty/Value`.

The `names_to` argument specifies how the new dataframe should look - for this specific case, the `.value` tells the function to keep the parts of the columns associated with it as header - in this case, the `.value` is the second entry, so it is paired with the second group in `names_pattern`; `store number` in `names_to` is paired with the first entry in `names_pattern`